# Fragment update w/ Master Detail?

Tags: android-fragments, master-detail, android-recyclerview

I'm using the Master-Detail flow template from Android Studio.
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById( R.id.movie_list );

```
mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter( this, mMovieList );
mAppController.setMovieAdapter( mMovieAdapter );
recyclerView.setAdapter( mMovieAdapter );
```

I've added a "DELETE" button to the main activity.

When I delete an item (a "movie"), the List is properly updated because
I call

```
mMovieList.remove( 0 );
mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

BUT
the tablet right side detail fragment is not updated.

How do I update the fragment when the DELETE button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete an item that is currently selected with it's detail(s) visible on a 2-pane layout, then you will **also** have to remove the detail/fragment.

i.e. `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();`